# My Router's Web interface doesn't have all features i need

Tags: router

I think my router doesn't have all the features I need like port forwarding, password and username changing etc.

I can access the interface through 192.168.1.1, with a username "admin" and password "1234" which is the default. But the options I can get after I login were

```
    STATUS
    -Device Info
    -ADSL
    SETUP
    -BASIC
    -SECURITY
    FIREWALL
    -Parent Control
```

And that's it. I can't even change my admin account for the router

my router is "BAUDTEC RN243R4-2T2R-A6"

Does my router had a second login account just to access its full web interface? if not, how can I push my router to give me all its features?

I tried "telnet 192.168.1.1"

I saw "portforward" option in there but when I use the command "config portforward" it always give me "ERROR: invalid privilege". How come that "admin" doesn't contain all the privilege to access the router?

BTW: I need "portforward" because I want my SQL Server accessible remotely, and this method is all I have left to do and my router is holding me. I can use 3rd party portforwarding software, but I think the ports I opened using them was only blocked by my router.

Comment: Do you own the router, or is it being provided by your ISP? It may well be that you just need to invest in some better equipment, but if may also be the case that your ISP has restrictions on your connection that they don't want you tampering with. In either case, however, exposing SQL Server to the internet is somewhat anti-recommended.

Comment: It is being provided by my ISP. So in this case, does my ISP restricts me from accessing all of its features? In regards on SQL Server, what do you recommend @NReilingh

Comment: I don't know anything about your ISP, but I'm sure they don't want you tampering with their equipment. You should get in touch with them and see if they can provide you with ONLY a DSL modem so you can purchase your own router with whatever features you need. If they require that you use their equipment and won't give you other options, then you're probably out of luck. As for SQL Server--perhaps consider having your new router run a VPN server?

Answer (score 1):

For **PLDT router logins** (2013-to date)

> **Real admins** 
> User Name: adminpldt
> Password: 1234567890
> User Name: pldtadmin 
> Password: 1234567890
>
> **Standard user** 
> User Name: admin 
> Password: 1234

Answer (score -1):

if you live in the Philippines and your ISP is PLDT, instead of using

User Name: admin
Password: 1234

try this

User Name: adminpldt
Password: 1234567890

Comment: The question says that the admin username is "admin", rather than "pldt" so I don't think this applies.

Comment: I use PLDT and this router. There are two users setup. One is "admin" and the other is "adminpldt" or "pldtadmin" in some deployments. The passwords are 1234 and 1234567890 respectively. The later gives more privileges than the former and allows port forwarding and others settings to be set, but you can't change the root SSID.